# How do I list all globally installed npm packages using yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

How do I list all globally installed npm packages using yarn?

I am new to yarn and to list all npm packages installed globally, I use npm list -g --depth=0 but is there a yarn equivalent?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT
`yarn global ls` is now deprecated. It has been replaced with `yarn global list` instead.**

---

**TL;DR:** `yarn global ls`

**Longer answer:**
Use `yarn global` for any global related task. Consider `yarn global` a command as a whole, and not in terms of `yarn` + the suffix `global` as with `npm` + `-g`.

`list` does not work with `yarn global` (though it works with `yarn` at the local level). Use the short version `ls` instead. `yarn global` has no concept of depth either (though `--depth=0` work for `yarn` at the local level).

For more details on `yarn global`: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global

Answer (score 13):

We should now use `yarn global list` since version 1.0.0 `yarn global ls` is deprecated.

[v1.0.0 !](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/tag/v1.0.0)